# Mousemove event working on document but not 'body'

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a div look like a turned-off light and when the mouse moves, the light turns on.

I am done with the part where the mouse movement turns the light on. Look at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CSdF9/1/).

jQuery code:

```
$(document).mousemove(function() {
    $('div').addClass('glow');
});
```

I have 2 questions about it

1. If I put 'body' instead of document, it doesn't work, why?
2. How can I detect the mouse stop?

Comment: Works fine for me if you change document to body. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CSdF9/3/. The body just happens to be much less tall than the document.

Comment: note that you need quotes around `body` e.g. `$('body')` if you're going to do this. or you can do `$(document.body)` with no quotes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1)** 'body' perfectly works but you must move the mouse over the body, which doesn't go until the bottom of the window (yes, the body is a strange and sometimes incoherent thing).

**2)** To detect mouse stop, the simplest solution is to use `setTimeout` and define a delay :

```
(function (){
    var i =0;
    var timer;
    $('body').mousemove(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        // 'body' doesn't work instead of document
        i += 1;
        $('p').text(function() {
            return 'Moved: ' + i;
        });
        $('div').addClass('glow');
        timer = setTimeout(function(){$('div').removeClass('glow')}, 2000);
    });     
})();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/2jJ3w/)

Comment: Thanks! It works great! But I can't understand the problem with `body`, the `background-color` applied to it extends to the whole window, so `jQuery` doesn't treats `body` same as `CSS` does?

Comment: That's why I say the body is a strange thing. Its background covers the window but it doesn't really extend until the bottom itself.

Comment: @SourabhVerma OctavianDamiean found [this specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background). It formalizes that the background is the special thing : for the body it extends over the whole canvas instead of over the body.

Comment: solution for body: `html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }` now body expands the entire viewport. Note: just setting body to 100% is meaningless because it is not the root element. It will (at that point) just assume 100% of it's parent (HTML element) which is not 100% of the viewport.