# Attempting to implement javascript on html page using Dreamweaver, (mouse tracker)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have successfully yoinked the code using javascript to replace the cursor with an animated gif from this page (https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/). I have successfully chucked her into Dreamweaver, I'm new to coding and I know it's way too much to start with but I want to make my website track the location of your cursor and change depending on which half of the page it's on. To be specific cursors derived from the painting: the creation of adam (the hands). Depending on which side it will switch between one of two cursors. I have found success in using a singular png as the cursor with the cursor: url() CSS method. This current method uses the CSS method of cursor: none in my style.css file.
The current javascript code is as follows

```
(function() {
  var follower, init, mouseX, mouseY, positionElement, printout, timer;

  follower = document.getElementById('follower');

  printout = document.getElementById('printout');

  mouseX = (event) => {
    return event.clientX;
  };

  mouseY = (event) => {
    return event.clientY;
  };

  positionElement = (event) => {
    var mouse;
    mouse = {
      x: mouseX(event),
      y: mouseY(event)
    };
    follower.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
    return follower.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
  };

  timer = false;

  window.onmousemove = init = (event) => {
    var _event;
    _event = event;
    return timer = setTimeout(() => {
      return positionElement(_event);
    }, 1);
  };

}).call(this);
```

and the style.css file is:

```
html {
  cursor: url("Cursor222.png");
  background: #E0CDA9;
}
#follower {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
#follower #circle1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: #0004D9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0em;
  width: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
}
#follower #circle2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(200,0,0,0.8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0em;
  width: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-left: 0em;
}
```

I'm *very* new to CSS and javascript, I don't know the way to implement conditional terms like if and else, can someone chuck me some support. I get it's a big ask and I can compensate you for your time.

Comment: So what is the issue exactly? I don't see a question or error message here. Are you asking how to switch between two cursor images? If so, one way is to use a class: create a 2nd rule that uses `html.right`, then check `if (mouseX(event) < window.innerWidth : 2)` and add/remove the class to the <html> element accordingly.

Comment: Also note that you don't need any of that JS code to change the cursor itself, for that all you need is a `cursor` rule in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample using an image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .cursor-left {
            /* cursor: url('url-to-image-1'), auto; */ // Add your cursor here
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .cursor-right {            
            /* cursor: url('url-to-image-2'), auto; */ // Add your cursor here
            cursor: cell;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="https://uploads1.wikiart.org/images/michelangelo/sistine-chapel-ceiling-creation-of-adam-1510.jpg" id="container" />

    <script>
        const containerElement = document.querySelector('#container');

        containerElement.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
            const imageWidth = containerElement.width;

            // const windowWidth = window.innerWidth; // for window

            if (e.clientX <= imageWidth / 2) {
                containerElement.classList.remove('cursor-right');
                containerElement.classList.add('cursor-left');
            } else {
                containerElement.classList.remove('cursor-left');
                containerElement.classList.add('cursor-right');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to do it with the whole page and not a specific container, attach the event listener to the `document`(`body` might not work for you, you can see why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550766/mousemove-event-working-on-document-but-not-body)) and track the width with the commented code. You can add as much cursor styles as you like by altering the mouse tracking constraints.